# problems with UUID column with Slick and H2

Tags: sql-server, scala, playframework, h2, slick

I have a play 2.4 app with slick 3.1 that hits a mssql db that has a UniqueIdentifier column, this uuid is the primary key, there is no autoinc column in the particular table.  I am also using [virtuslabs/unicorn](https://github.com/VirtusLab/unicorn) for the typesafe ids and their base repository.  I generate the UUID on the server and slick sends it to the db and everything works great.

My problem is when I try to mock the db with H2 for my tests.  I have had a few problems getting this working but I have been able to figure them out accept for this one.

When slick builds the insert query for h2 it does not include the uuid.  I know that when you have an autoinc primary key and you do an insert slick strips whatever value you have as the key and uses the db generated one so I think thats what it is doing but in this case I want to send the value I have generated.  This works with the mssql driver but not the h2 driver.

I would have thought this was a problem with Unicorn not knowing how to deal with uuids but then it wouldnt work with mssql either

Any advice?

Comment: Be careful using a uniqueidentifier as your primary key. Is it also your clustered index? If so, you need to plan regularly defragmenting that index as the fragmentation will exceed 99% with as few as 1,000 rows. It is not a great choice for a clustered index.

Comment: Thanks, this is a pre-existing db that I don't have control over but I will keep this in mind and pass it on

Comment: It doesn't mean you have to change the structure. But clustering on a random value is not going to help any application. As for the question at hand it requires a very specific knowledge base with a number of applications. I have no help there. Hopefully somebody will.